# Perpendicular distance from stright line to point on arc

Tags: geometry, pi

I have a line with a circular arc cutting through it at 2 points, A and B.

Given that I know the length of line CD (which is the distance between line AB and the highest point on the arc - perpendicular to AB) and I know the length of line AB, is it possible to calculate the distance between any point on line AB and its corresponding perpendicular point on the arc?
for example, if point E is half way between points A and C, how do I calculate the length of EF?

[image]

Comment: Certainly you *can*. Are you asking *how*? Or, what's the best way exactly?

Comment: Yes, because you can find the radius of the circle. If $AC=b$ and the radius is $a$ then extend the line CD down until you reach a point which is a distance a from A, B  and D. Can you relate a to b and h?

Comment: edited to be clearer - yes, I am asking how.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not tried anything since It is beyond me. I can add some context though. I want to build a picket fence where the top of each picket between 2 posts follows an arc, from the left post curving down to the lowest point in the center point between the posts and then back up to the right post. I would like to write a formula so that I can determine the length (height) of each picket given where it is located between the posts. I think finding an answer to the above question will help me with such a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

One method can be this:

If $CD=h$ and $AB=b$ then the Radius of the circle is:

$R=\frac{b^2+4h^2}{8h}$

Calculate R.As said in comment extend DC to get $A_1$ such that $DA_1=R$, $A_1$  is the center of the circle. Draw a circle with radius R , center at $A_1$. Draw a line parallel with AB passing $A_1$, it intersects the circle at points G and I, GI is the diameter of the circle. Extend FE to meet GI at J. In right angled triangle FGI we have:

$FJ^2=GI\times JI=(R-d)(R+d)=R^2-d^2$

where d is the distance between CD and EF. Finding FJ we have:

$EF=FJ-(R-h)=FJ+h-R$

Comment: 2 questions while I try to figure out your answer :)
1) in your diagram it looks like CD is exactly half the radius. In my question, CD could be any fraction of the radius. Does your answer still work in that case?
2) is it really CD=h and CD=b as you state on the second line?

Thanks

Comment: I should think $CA=b$. Your diagram is the top half of the circle here.

Comment: @Jralford, Sorry for tthe typo. I corrected the error. c can be anywhere including the position on your picture.

Comment: Awesome. Implemented in my picket fence code and works like a charm! Big thanks @sirous

Comment: @Jralford, You are welcome .